# What's the use of C4711 "function selected for inline expansion" Visual C++ warning?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, warnings, inline

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k402bt7y(v=vs.80).aspx) Visual C++ can emit C4711 warning: *function X selected for inline expansion* if the compiler decides to inline a function that was not marked inline.

I don't see how this warning can be useful. Suppose I compile my code and see this warning. Now what? Why would I care?

Comment: I'm really not sure why people are posting answers that it's "not on my default". No, Visual Studio defaults to warning level 3. I *always* change it to `/Wall`. I never stopped to think that everyone else didn't do the same... This is a great question; the only explanation I've been able to come up with is it might clue you in to some subtle bug inlining could cause (but that seems fairly rate).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It isn't on by default. You can turn it on if for some reason you'd like to know when functions are inlined. This can be relevant if, say, code size is at a severe premium, or you were expecting to jump into the function from outside the module, or you need the assembly to look a certain way. It can help track down code generation bugs as well.

It's purely informational.

Comment: one could hope that purely informational message would not stop compilation when `/Werror` (or whatever the MS switch, I can't seem to remember) is on :/

Comment: @Matthieu:  If you want it to, it will.  Most people don't want to, that's why it's off by default.  But if you feel that it's an important enough warning to stop compilation, then you're free to turn the warning on.

Comment: @Matthieu M. : That would be `/WX`. But I can't understand why you'd combine `/WX /Wall`. I could imagine a future compiler switch `/WX3`, i.e. "every warning of severity 1-3 is an error", but warning level 4 has an insane level of false positives.

Comment: @MSalters: yes, positively insane, in fact so insane that I don't activate it on my projects --> too much warnings in VC++ own STL files to be useful. I use `/W3 /WX`, but I'd really like to have some kind of "diagnonis build" configuration (kind of cheap static analysis), too many false positives kill a warning though :/

Comment: @MatthieuM. just pass `/wd4710 /wd4711` arguments to compiler. Will save you a lot of console output space. You can also re-enable this warnings in case you'll find yourself in very niche corner case where you actually need this warnings.

Comment: @MatthieuM. _ too much warnings in VC++ own STL files to be useful. _ Its very easy to fix. just use `#pragma warning( push, 1 ) *all your external includes*
#pragma warning( pop )` You will still have the benefits of `/Wall` for your own code, but now you will never see any warning from the outside code/libraries.